# Moving twitter feed iframe using jquery appendTo but html in iframe doesnt load

Tags: jquery

I am working with software that does not directly allow me to edit certain sections directly. As a work around I can add js to the header/footer to edit these sections. I would like to move my twitter feed from one section to another section but when I do this the HTML in the iframe is missing. I believe it has something to do with the iframe not reloading. It does work when I do this in jsfiddle however. http://jsfiddle.net/u8kt067s/

```
<div class="editable">
<p>This content can be edited directly using html</p>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Jenny_Lane4" data-widget-id="646719649313374208">Tweets by @Jenny_Lane4</a>
</div>

<div class="cantedit">
<p>This content cannot be edited directly, you must use a script. 
This is where I would like the twitter feed to appear</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload the twitter script after you move the div.

```
$(function(){
    $('.twitter-timeline').appendTo('div.cantedit');
    reload();
});

function reload(){
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2vb3L0j/

Comment: Thank you Gregg! Unfortunately, this only appears to work if you refresh the page after loading it.

Comment: When you click the link to the fiddle you don't see the twitter feed in the new location? I do. The $(function() runs on document load. which moves your twitter-timeline div. Then calls the reload function which reloads the twitter timeline. all this should happen on the initial page load.